# Jenkins pipeline credentials for all stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins scripted pipeline with multiple stages, all of the stages require the same password for interaction with third-party API.

```
node {
    stage ('stage1') {
        sh 'curl --user login:password http://trird-party-api'
    }
    stage ('stage2') {
        sh 'curl --user login:password http://trird-party-api'
    }
}
```

For obvious reasons I want to keep this password safe, e.g. in Jenkins credentials.

The only secure way I've found is to add `withCredentials` section, but it must be added to each pipeline stage, e.g:

```
node {
    stage ('stage1') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '02647301-e655-4858-a7fb-26b106a81458', variable: 'mypwd')]) {
            sh 'curl --user login:$mypwd http://trird-party-api'
        }
    }
    stage ('stage2') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '02647301-e655-4858-a7fb-26b106a81458', variable: 'mypwd')]) {
            sh 'curl --user login:$mypwd http://trird-party-api'
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is not OK because real pipeline is really complicated.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using Jenkins global variables or password parameter ? Passwords stored there are encrypted by Jenkins and not easily visible.

Comment: user1550159 the reason is security - lots of people have access to Jenkins log and if password is in variable or parameter it could be seen in log

Answer (score 7):

According to [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182807/jenkins-use-withcredentials-in-global-environment-section) and [this tutorial](https://github.com/puzzle/jenkins-techlab/blob/master/labs/12_credentials.md), you should be able to specify the needed credentials in a declarative pipeline like so:

```
environment {
    AUTH = credentials('02647301-e655-4858-a7fb-26b106a81458')
}

stages {
    stage('stage1') {
        sh 'curl --user $AUTH_USR:$AUTH_PSW http://third-party-api'
    }
    stage('stage2') {
        sh 'curl --user $AUTH_USR:$AUTH_PSW http://third-party-api'
    }
```

With a scripted pipeline, you're pretty much relegated to using `withCredentials` around the things you want to have access to them. Have you tried surrounding the stages with the credentials, as in:

```
node {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '02647301-e655-4858-a7fb-26b106a81458', variable: 'mypwd')]) {
        stage ('stage1') {
            sh 'curl --user login:password http://trird-party-api'
        }
        stage ('stage2') {
            sh 'curl --user login:password http://trird-party-api'
        }
    }
}
```